# hide a model field in form in django

Tags: django

I want to hide one field of model from form, that is a time fiels which automatically filed.

```
check_out_time = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes = 60))
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
```

I want to display only first name and last name in form, not the check out time. Please help me, how to hide any field in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        exclude = ('check_out_time', )
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to conditionally exclude a field:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if <your logic here>:
           del self.fields['check_out_time']

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
```

Comment: thanks, its working. Can i include that field based on some condition later

Comment: The conditional exclude fails for me. Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited. If I define '__all__', then I get the error Key 'check_out_time' not found in 'YourForm'

Comment: Special value `__all__`  is used to indicate that all fields in the *model* should be used.

Comment: Since `check_out_time` is an extra field .. it won't be included if ``__all__`` is used as fields attribute.